# Is fessus a participle?

Tags: etymology, adjective, participle

The adjective *fessus* (wearied, tired, fatigued, worn out, weak, feeble, infirm) sounds and looks like it could well be a participle.
If there is a verb, I would assume it to mean something in the direction of "to weaken" or "to burden".
Is there such a verb, or has there ever been one?
I found no suitable verb starting with *fed-* or *fet-*.
The meanings and conjugations of *fetare* and *fetere* do not match.
The verb *fendere* could be suitable, but it seems to survive only in compounds (*offendere*, *defendere*), and the past participle seems to be *fensus*.

I know that proving non-existence is hard.
If you think there is no such verb, it is perfectly acceptable if you argue why.

This is related to the [later question about the difference between *fessus* and *defessus*](http://latin.stackexchange.com/q/2239/79).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Maybe.

There is a verb *fatīscō, fatīscere, —, ???*, meaning to fall apart or collapse. (Sometimes it also acts like a deponent verb, *fatīscor, fatīscī*, with the same meaning.) But it's practically nonexistent in the past tense, and doesn't have a proper perfect system.

*Fessus* **could** be considered a perfect participle for *fatīscō*, with the inchoative *-isc-* removed and a vowel change. But there isn't much evidence for this except the similar meanings; I haven't found any ancient authors mentioning that they were the same verb.

There is also the verb *fatīgō* "to tire out" and the adverb *affatim* "considered to be enough", which **could** come from a noun **fatis* meaning something like "tiredness". But no such noun is attested anywhere. Servius's *Commentary on the Aeneid* mentions **fatim* once, but other than that only the derived forms survive.

Comment: De Vaan indeed connects *fessus, fatisco, fatigo* (the headword is the last of these, p. 204-5). The vowel of *fessus* is odd -- he derives it by analogy from the compound form *defessus*.