# What's the difference between fessus and defessus?

Tags: meaning, word-choice

I'm curious to know what the difference is between *fessus* and *defessus*. Is *de-* simply acting as an intensifying prefix? Suppose I were tired at the end of night, and wanted to go to sleep. Would I say *sum defessus* or *sum fessus*? Or suppose an athlete, after running a long race, was exhausted at the end. Which would be the right choice?

Lastly, which is more common in Latin literature? Do authors tend to choose one over the other?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Usage

Lewis and Short glosses [*fessus*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dfessus) as:

> wearied, tired, fatigued; worn out, weak, feeble, infirm

It lists *defessus* (which is the past participle of [*dēfĕtiscor*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Ddefetiscor) as a synonym. It has a similar meaning:

> to become tired or wearied; to grow weary, faint; to be exhausted

So far, this isn't helpful. Our breakthrough comes, though, when we realize that [*de-*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=d%C4%93&la=la&can=d%C4%930&d=Perseus:text:1999.04.0059:entry=de1&i=1#lexicon) can function as an *intensifying prefix*, as in L&S II.2.c., which includes many examples:

> **With reference to the terminus of the action:** defero, defigo, demitto, etc.; **hence also trop., with reference to the extent of the action, to the uttermost, to exhaustion, throughout**: debacchor, debello, dedolo, delino, delibuo, etc.: defatigo, delaboro, delasso, etc.; **hence freq. a mere strengthening of the fundamental idea, = valde, thoroughly, much:** demiror, demitigo, etc.

It is almost certainly in this sense that *defessus* indicates a more thorough exhaustion than *fessus*. This is confirmed by the [*Copious and Critical Latin-English Dictionary*](https://books.google.com/books?id=-qpFAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA368&lpg=PA368&dq=fessus+defessus):

> **Defessus**: entirely exhausted **so as to be obliged to give up**.

This aspect of "giving up" appears in other comparative works as well (such as [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=pWQZAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA292&lpg=PA292&dq=fessus+defessus)).

It's impossible to speak of rules, here, but the nuance appears to be something like the following:

> **Defessus sum quaeritando.** --*I am tired of looking [so I am stopping].*
>
> **Fessus sum quaeritando.** --*I am tired of looking.*

Some examples don't include this "stopping" nuance, in which case you are safe to assume that it just is intensitive, e.g. "I am *very* tired" or "I am exhausted."

### Frequency

Both forms are listed as frequent in classical Latin, though *fessus* is about five times more frequent. This is a difference between *common* and *extremely common*, and both are easily understood.

- *defessus*: [132 matches in the Packhum Corpus](http://latin.packhum.org/search?q=%23defess)
- *fessus*: [640 matches in the Packhum Corpus](http://latin.packhum.org/search?q=%23fess)

Comment: Great answer! One question. In your examples, you put the gerund quaeritando in what I assume is the ablative case. Do the adjectives fessus and defessus take the ablative in this construction? e.g. Defessus sum eos pugnando. (I am tired of fighting them.)

Comment: @ktm5124 Yes, L&S says that it can take the infinitive or ablative (gerund or noun). That quote is actually from Plautus.

Comment: For the semantic contribution of *de-*, compare *out* in *worn out*.

Comment: @TKR Interesting!

Answer (score 6):

An easy way to think about it (I offer this as a brief addition to Brian's excellent answer above) is that *fessus* means "tired" and *defessus*, as TKR suggests, means "tired out." Latin verbs with prefixes often match English verbs with prepositions. (*Monstro* v. *demonstro* = "show" v. "point out," etc.)

Comment: Hmm... I wonder if *emonstrare* is "to show off". :)